# Full screen keyboard shortcut not working on selected applications (Chromium)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04, chromium

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on (though I don't think it matters) a Lenovo X1 Carbon 7th gen.

The problem is that I can not toggle full-screen on some applications (e.g. Chromium).

If I launch Chromium from the terminal with the command
"chromium-browser --start-fullscreen"
then it will open in full-screen.

Though I can't seem to achieve this same state otherwise.

I've tried creating a keyboard shortcut in settings->keyboard->toggle-full-screen-mode as 'Ctrl + F' and while this works for most applications it does not work for Chromium.

What is the problem here, and what can I do to fix it?

Thank you,

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. For me, Chromium (installed as a flatpak, though) full screens both when typing its internal shortcut (F11) as the system wide shortcut I defined for me (Ctrl+Super+F in my case).

Comment: Okay, I can access full screen via the drop down menu in the top right (the one you access by pressing the triple dots) but I can not seem to do so via the keyboard. I think it might be a problem with Fn-lock but I know exactly what it is.

Edit: In any case it is not a problem with Chromium I don't think.